# Count the number of ways to make changes

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, subset-sum, coin-change

I have a set of coins 1,2, 4, 10, 20, 40, 100, 200, 400, 1000, 2000 cents. I want to find out how many ways to pays for a certain amount (<= 6000). My current solution in c++ is using dynamic programming is as followed:

```
long long d[6010];
int coin[] = {1, 2, 4, 10, 20, 40, 100, 200, 400, 1000, 2000};
d[0] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {  // iterate through all coins
    for (int j = 1; j <= 6000; j++)
        d[j] += d[j - coin[i]];
printf("%lld\n", d[20]);
```

However my output is incorrect: -956301262. Is it because of any overflow problem?

Comment: In first place, this is not C++ code but C.

Comment: `j - coin[i]` can come out negatvie.

Comment: Thanks @Pubby for your answer. I have been able to fixed the problem.

Comment: My answer for amount = 5999 is 1684271704. However according to [Algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_147) it should be 181000196059736. Any idea why?
PS: I multiply the original amount by 20 for conveniences.

Comment: Thats why I stored it in a long long array. The original set of coins is five time the value of each in the coin value (in cents), to make it more space efficient, I reduce the coin value and the required amount by 5 times. When I read an amount, it is a float and the unit is dollar. Converting to cents: `100*amount/5 = 20 *amount`.

Comment: How is your DP algorithm the same as the one on algorithmist? You are simply assigning values from `d` to other elements in `d` without ever changing anything. Can you update your code so that it reflects what you currently have?

Comment: My bad, missing a plus (+) sign.

Comment: Still, the DP algo requires a table of size n*m. I don't understand how you try to get away with an array of size n?

Comment: Check it by hand with smaller numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use two-dimensional array of size 6001x11 (in your case) to store all possible values. Start with d[0][0] and iterate until d[6000][10] which will contain the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your algorithm should work, I would have gone recursively over each denomination from higher to lower (looping over the different amount). While using a lookup table, presumably similar to your d.

Something along the lines of:

```
howmanyways(sorted_denominations_set_starting_with_1, target amount):
if this is already in the lookup table return the result
else if sorted_denominations_set_starting_with_1 is {1}, then return target amount
else loop over 0 to target amount/last_set_element
   return the sum of results for howmanyways(sorted_denominations_set_starting_with_1 without the largest element, target amount-last_set_element*loop_index)
keep whatever you return in the lookup table
```

and return howmanyways({1, 2, 4, 10, 20, 40, 100, 200, 400, 1000, 2000}, target amount);

Comment: So you mean I should change the outer loop to: `for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)`? I tried and the result is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are backwards. The coin-denomination loop should be your inner loop.

Your array assignment also just doesn't make sense. You're currently just summing the values of change that differ from your target by a particular denomination of coin.

You should probably have a vector of vectors as your data structure. Each time you're running through your inner loop, you should be inserting a new vector into your data structure. This vector should be a set of coins which has a sum equal to the value of interest.